# java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex || Android

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

**
While runing the code I encounter this error "Unable to merge dex || Android in the android studio

This is basically use of map in the android application**

*This is the Build.gradle code*

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.npatel7.carparking"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "image1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Please assist me